# Best File Structure with ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: angularjs

I will begin web project with AngularJS and want to organize my files appropriately including Web Api.

What is the best structure to use?

Comment: This isn't the type of question for SO - there are plenty of examples on the internet.

Comment: it is definitely depends on the project ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The detailed explanation of file structure in AngularJS is explained in *AngularJS Up & Running by Shyam Seshadri & Brad Green*.

Here is few tips from the book.

- Have one controller, service, directive, or filter per file. Don’t club them into large
  single files.
- Don’t have one giant module. Break up your applications into smaller modules. Let
  your main application be composed of multiple smaller, reusable modules.
- Prefer to create modules and directories by functionality (authorization, adminservices,
  search, etc.), over type (controllers, services, directives). This makes your
  code more reusable.
- **Groups by functionality** (login, autohorization)
- Creates folder to reusable components (datepicker, widgets)
- Creates seperate folder to third-party dependencies.